# Calling .net dll from NSIS

Tags: wcf, nsis

I want to validate the username and password before proceeding with the NSIS install.

When I click on the next button, I want to check whether the user is authorized to install the application. For this check, I want to make a WCF call from my .NET application. It will return true or false.

Based on that, I will proceed or abort my installation. I tried using the `CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD` plugin. Since I am referring to a service reference, it is throwing the exception:

`Error calling .net dll method`

Here is the NSIS script that I have so far:

```
Name "Test CLRDLL MakeLogEntry" 
OutFile "TestCLRDLL.exe"
Page instfiles

Section 
    start InitPluginsDir 
    SetOutPath $PLUGINSDIR 
    File "MyDll.dll" 
    CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD "MyDll.dll" "namespace.classname" \ "ValidateLogin" 3 "Myserviceaddress/Servicename.svc"; "username" "password" 
    pop $0 
    MessageBox MB_OK $0 
sectionEnd 

Function .onGUIEnd 
    CLR::Destroy 
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Can you post the nsis script that you have so far?

Comment: Name "Test CLRDLL MakeLogEntry"
OutFile "TestCLRDLL.exe"
Page instfiles

SEction start
InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $PLUGINSDIR
File "MyDll.dll"

CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD "MyDll.dll" "namespace.classname" \
  "ValidateLogin" 3 "http://Myserviceaddress/Servicename.svc" "username" "password"

pop $0
MessageBox MB_OK $0

sectionEnd


Function .onGUIEnd
   CLR::Destroy
FunctionEnd

Comment: Please always add clarifications to the question to improve the question.

Answer (score 3):

You should also know, that CLR::Call plugin works only with .Net 2.0 assemblies (not higher).
So maybe you should recompile your dll.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.

The CLR::Call plugin [only supports .Net 2.0 assemblies](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Call_.NET_DLL_methods_plug-in#Prerequisites).

[WCF was introduced in .NET 3.0](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e85d3167-1e22-4962-b091-ad0a82b36026/).